# Should I partition/subpartition my table?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

**Case**

1. The system has `dispositives`, basically formed by `id, type, name`.
2. I may have N `dispositives`.
3. I have a table to store a `log` of all `dispositives`. This is the biggest table in the system. (Now counting 100 mi records)
4. The `log` table has: `id_dispositive, date, status`.

**Problem**

Obviously this huge data it's causing performance issues. I must store at least two months log values..

Today I have this `dispositives` by `type`:

```
TYPE     COUNT
---------------
1         78956  
2         125161
3         13213
4         6112
5         25426
6         12314
7         1241
8         622
```

I also have some business logic to feed this `log` table. Anyways, here is my thoughts:

**My "solution"**

I was thinking on partition this `log` table. Here is the questions:

1. Does it worth it?
2. Should I partition by type?
3. Should I partition by type AND subpartition by DATE?
4. Can I do it programmatically?

As this types are dynamics, users can delete/insert new ones.

So if they delete some type, I must delete all logs of that type.
As if they insert some type, I must register(store) all logs of that type.

**EDIT according Francesco Serra's answer**

I'm trying to create the table like this:

```
create table log(
       id_dispositive    number,
       type       number,
       date_verification    date,
       status  number
)
partition by range (date_verification) 
subpartition by list (type)  
subpartition TEMPLATE (
    SUBPARTITION type1 VALUES (1),
    SUBPARTITION type2 VALUES (2),
    SUBPARTITION type3 VALUES (3),
    SUBPARTITION type4 VALUES (4)
)(                           
interval (numtoyminterval(1,'MONTH'))(
   partition p0816 values less than (to_date('01/09/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'))
));
```

and i'm getting:

```
ORA-14004: PARTITION keyword not found.
```

Comment: How are you going to partition by type if it's not a part of log table?
If you ussually access by date, you should at least try to partition by date. Use DBMS_REDEFINITION to partition the table in order to minimize downtime.

Comment: Well, it has the `id_dispositive`. I can get its type with it... Like partition all ids of type X?

Comment: You can create automatic partition on number columns (when is possible new rows are added in the right partition, if the partition doesn't exist it's created). You can add subpartitions using a template. Tell me if you are interested in this solution.

Comment: I really need to create based on the type, @FrancescoSerra... is this possible?

Comment: @MarllonNasser yes you can actually since 11R1 with reference partitioning. Check this post: https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/partitioning-enhancements-11gr1#reference_partitioning

Comment: hello @vercelli, I don't see any examples showing that it's possible to do that... I mean I don't have the `type column` as my FK.. unless i'm able to create FKs based on others values (`id_dispositie` must exist in another table AND of type X,Y,Z, which I think it's not possible either :(

Comment: @MarllonNasser If you look at the example, the father table is partitioned by date and the child table uses the same partitions as the fathers. In your case you should partition `dispositive` by `type` and since `log` table has a FK to `dispositive` on `id_dispositive` partition by reference on that FK

Comment: yes I saw that... but how the subpartition would work? One partition for each child's id?

Comment: Whether partitioning will help depends to a large extent on what sort of query you're going to be running. If the queries you need to speed up have a type predicate then it may help, if you're always selecting all types then it won't make any difference.

Comment: I need to filter by types and `date` range... so I think it will help right?

Comment: What is the cardinality of `TYPE`?  That is, does it have a large number of unique values or a small number?  If each type is only used a few times then it probably won't help to partition by it - an index would work much better.

Comment: I would have N `dispositives` to 1 `TYPE`. And it's a small number of it... 10 in the **worst** scenario. I'm thinking on partition and subpartition and use indexes.... is there a chance to this approach decrease/disrupt performace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try in this way: use INTERVAL to tell oracle to create automatic partitions. You must define column (number or date) and an interval (in my example 1 month). Oracle will put in the same partition all row in the same interval (in this case in the same month). If the partition doesn't exist will be created.

```
create table log(
       id_dispositive    number,
       date    date,
       status  number,
       type    number
)
partition by range (date)                              
interval (numtoyminterval(1,'MONTH'))(
   partition p0701 values less than (to_date('2007-02-01','yyyy-mm-dd'))
);
```

The same can be done also with type column. More information: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-partitioning-084209.html.

Every partition can be subpartitioned using TEMPLATE key.

```
create table log(
       id_dispositive    number,
       date    date,
       status  number,
       type    number
)
partition by range (date) interval (numtoyminterval(1,'MONTH'))
subpartition by list (type)  
subpartition TEMPLATE (
    SUBPARTITION types1 VALUES (1, 2) TABLESPACE tbs_1,
    SUBPARTITION types2 VALUES (3, 4) TABLESPACE tbs_1
)                          
(
   partition p0701 values less than (to_date('2007-02-01','yyyy-mm-dd'))
);
```

In this case you can't create an automatic subpartition, if a new type will be add you have to run an alter table statment. Here more informations; https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/part_admin.htm#i1006655.

**In your example:**

```
create table prova_log(
       id_dispositive    number,
       type       number,
       date_verification    date,
       status  number
)
partition by range (date_verification) interval (numtoyminterval(1,'MONTH'))
subpartition by list (type)  
subpartition TEMPLATE (
    SUBPARTITION type1 VALUES (1),
    SUBPARTITION type2 VALUES (2),
    SUBPARTITION type3 VALUES (3),
    SUBPARTITION type4 VALUES (4)
)                          
(
   partition p0816 values less than (to_date('01/09/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'))
);
```

If you try to insert:

```
insert into prova_log values (1,1,TO_DATE('10/10/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'),1);
```

you will see 2 partition on your table.

Now I've tested it!

Comment: what about dynamic inserts?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. In any way: when you insert a new row in the table Oracle put it in the right partition/subpartition, if the partition doesn't exists it will be created.

Comment: what if I want to create a subpartititon for each type? can I do that programmatically? Somehow if the subpartition doesn't exists that oracle creates?

Comment: subpartitions can't be created dynamically. For a new subpartition you must execute an alter table and modify the template definition.

Comment: I just tried to create the table like you suggested and i'm getting `ORA-14004` as edition on question.

Comment: it's not creating new partitions (based on the date). It's only creating the first partition `P0816` declared in the `create` statment.

Comment: Interval is set to 1 month (1 partition every month starting from 1/9/2016). Have you inserted a date at least 1 month after 1/9/2016? I've updated my answer, on my schema after the insert there are 2 partions (default one, and a new one).

Comment: I tried to insert a date at least 1 month before 1/9/2016 and it didn't created another patition for values before 1/7/2016, for example.

Comment: As you can see default partition will contain all row with date_verification LESS THAN (= earlier) 1/9/2016. Change table definition if your start date is earlier.

Comment: hmmmm ok...what if I want to drop/delete a subpartition/partition data? can you show an example? Also, can I use `index` to customize querys? can `index` be used with partitions?

Comment: The table is an usual table: yes you can use index (see local and global index on Oracle documentation) and yes you can drop/delete partitions with usual sql code.